# How to compare two field value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[order page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwhjI.jpg)I have created one IMS. In that, on order page, I have to validate the product quantity that it should not allow entering more than the available quantity. Below is my code (qty[] is the available quantity in stock and aqty[] is quantity entered while creating the order)

```
<tr id="row_1">
                       <td>
                        <select class="form-control select_group product" data-row-id="row_1" id="product_1" name="product[]" style="width:100%;" onchange="getProductData(1)" required>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php foreach ($products as $k => $v): ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name="hsn[]" id="hsn_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                          <input type="hidden" name="hsn_value[]" id="hsn_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate_1" class="form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)"></td>
                         <td>
                             <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                             <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                         </td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="aqty[]" id="aqty_1" class="form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)"></td>
                            <td>
                          <input type="text" name="unit[]" id="unit_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                          <input type="hidden" name="unit_value[]" id="unit_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                          <input type="hidden" name="amount_value[]" id="amount_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name="gst[]" id="gst_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                          <input type="hidden" name="gst_value[]" id="gst_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name="gst_amount[]" id="gst_amount_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                          <input type="hidden" name="gst_amount_value[]" id="gst_amount_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name="last_amount[]" id="last_amount_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                          <input type="hidden" name="last_amount_value[]" id="last_amount_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeRow('1')"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>
                     </tr>
```

This is how i am comparing two fields value

```
$('#qty_value_1,#aqty_1').on('keyup', function() {
    var btn = $('button:contains("Submit")');
    if (parseFloat($('#qty_value_1').val()) >= parseFloat($('#aqty_1').val())) {
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        btn.prop('disabled', true);
    }
})
```

Above validation is only working for first product if i enter second product or more this logic is not working

Comment: You're only ever attaching the handler to the `#..._1` elements. I'd suggest using a common class and capturing all the rows instead.

Comment: how can I use a class in it if u have example than please give

Comment: `qty_value_1` is a hidden field. How do you expect a keyup event on it?

Comment: I am the beginner in jquery which event we can use for hidden filed in jquery

Comment: It's got nothing to do with jquery. It's not possible for you to press a key on a hidden field since it's, well, hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I played a little with your code…

- Using `class`es instead of `id`s to simplify,
- Using unary `+` operator instead of `parseFloat`,
- Changed code to make it work for any `tr`.

… and ended-up with that working snippet:
(I've removed the `hidden` to be able to play with the values)

```js
// Changed ids to classes
$('.qty, .aqty').on('keyup', function() {

  var btn = $('button:contains("Submit")');

  // Get tr elements
  var trs = $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr');

  $(trs).each(function(i, elm) {
    var qty = $(elm).find('.qty');
    var aqty = $(elm).find('.aqty');

    btn.prop('disabled', false);           // Enabled by default
    if (+$(qty).val() < +$(aqty).val()) { // Using Unary +
      btn.prop('disabled', true);          // Disabled if qty < aqty
      return;                              // Exit
    }

  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>aqty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
        <input name="qty_value[]" class="qty form-control" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="aqty[]" class="aqty form-control" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_2" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
        <input name="qty_value[]" class="qty form-control" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="aqty[]" class="aqty form-control" required></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button disabled>Submit</button>
```

Feel free to comment me for anything.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is also showing me the error of duplicate attribute class

Comment: @karuna Try without using the unary `+` operator. If `let` wasn't working, maybe `+` doesn't work as well.

Comment: I have tried without using + operator but still, it is not working

Comment: @karuna It's working as you wish in the snippet? What differs in your code?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="qty form-control" autocomplete="off"> <input type="text" name="aqty[]" id="aqty_1" class="aqty form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)">

Comment: and in my code only one submit button is there instead of every row

Comment: @karuna you changed your HTML and removed the `td`s. In my code, I am using the parent `tr` to target the other elements…

Comment: <td>
                             <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                             <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="qty form-control" autocomplete="off">
                         </td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="aqty[]" id="aqty_1" class="aqty form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)"></td>

Comment: @karuna Is your button outside your table like : `</table>
<button>Submit</button>` ? Your question doesn't show where the button is. You may have to update it. I've updated my answer anyway.

Comment: @karunakar, how do you want the button to behave with multiple rows ?

Comment: when we click on submit button it should check all row quantity and if a condition for all row satisfy than the only button should be enabled

Answer (score 0):

The following code captures the change event of the `aqty` input. When the value is changed it iterates through all rows and checks if any of the values are greater than the available quantity for that row. if it is then the button is disabled.

I've used the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the inputs. You can also make use of class names to simplify the selection. e.g. `qty` can have class `qty` and `aqty` can be `aqty`. You then select the inputs in jquery by `".qty"` and `".aqty"`

```js
function updateSubmitStatus() {
  var submitDisabled = false;

  // iterate through inputs
  $("[name='aqty[]']").each(function(a) {
  
    var available = parseFloat($(this).closest("tr").find("[name='qty[]']").val()); // find available quantity for the row
    var ordered = parseFloat($(this).val());
    
    if (isNaN(ordered)) {
      ordered = 0; // invalid number. reset to zero.
      $(this).val(ordered)
    }
    
    if (available < ordered) {
      submitDisabled = true;
      return false; // submit disabled. break out of loop.
    }
  });

  $("button:contains('Submit')").prop('disabled', submitDisabled);
}

$("[name='aqty[]']").change(updateSubmitStatus);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off" value="5">
      <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="aqty[]" id="aqty_1" class="form-control" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off" value="10">
      <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="aqty[]" id="aqty_1" class="form-control" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I have tried this code in my but it is also working for first product only if second product value is greater than second than also button is enable which i don't want

Comment: If you try running the snippet does it work as expected? Could you update your answer with an example of at least 2 rows?

Comment: after trying for two rows I have given the comment

Comment: Your question has only one row. Add an example of at least 2 rows. And I asked you to try "Run Snippet" in my example. Did you try that?

Comment: I have given the screenshot of the output I got

Comment: Screenshots are not very helpful and your update still only has 1 row.. .....and _again_ did you try running the snippet?

Comment: in my page, multiple tables are available then how can I select the particular table